# How does namecoin compare and contrast to bitcoin?

Tags: currencies, namecoin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Namecoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/what-are-namecoins)

It seems to me, a bitcoin newbie, that namecoin is something entirely different but has some similarities.   I would like to hear it from the bitcoin community what they think of namecoin and what it seeks to accomplish.

Comment: Helpful: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/169/are-the-capabilities-of-namecoin-a-strict-superset-of-bitcoin

Comment: Also: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1487/what-are-namecoins